# how does kotlin allow using minus operator on java time objects

Tags: kotlin

if i do in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val newInstant = Instant.now() - Duration.ofMinutes(10)
```

it seems to work as expected, ie 10 mins are subtracted from the current time.

However, I want to know how is this possible since `Instant` is a java class and doesnt implement the operator overloading functions of Kotlin. So what Kotlin mechanism is being used to implement the `minus` operator in the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Instant` has `public Instant minus(TemporalAmount amountToSubtract)` method, which is used as binary operator `-`.

> Since Java has no way of marking methods for which it makes sense to use the operator syntax, Kotlin allows using any Java methods with the right name and signature as operator overloads and other conventions (invoke() etc.) Calling Java methods using the infix call syntax is not allowed.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#operators,
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html